# category filter angular selection dropdown

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, filter

I have implemented the dropdown of the category names to display. The action I want to create is whichever name is selected, It filters by the devices which the category belongs to.

For example: in Rails console, I can do Category.first.devices.first. This will give me the first category the first device belongs to. I'm trying do the same in angular using a filter. I have a join table with device_id and category_id.

In my HTML:

```
Category:
<select ng-model="filterCategory" ng-options="category.name for category in categories"> </select>
```

Comment: I would just use underscore.js or lo-dash whichever is installed on your project.  If one of those isn't on your project add it.  You won't regret it.

Comment: Do you really need a filter? you could just add a `ng-change` function to the `select`, then actually filter (or fetch from a service/db) the list of devices from the selected category in the function, and set the result in the view controller scope.